# Group of equations together - middle one getting unexpected indentation

Tags: equations, align, indentation, split

Here I am want to create three lines of equations together so that they will get the same equation numbering for all three equations. However, when I use `aligned` or `split`, I get an unexpected indentation. I want the second line to be aligned with the first and third line.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We recall the Bellman equation

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split} \label{eq:bellman-eq} 
    Q^{\pi}_{h}(s, a) &= (r_h + \mathbb{P}_h V^{\pi}_{h+1})(s, a),\\
    V^{\pi}_{h}(s) &= \langle Q^{\pi}_{h}(s,\cdot), \pi_h(\cdot \mid s) \rangle,\\ 
    V^{\pi}_{H+1}(s) &= 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your **expected** indentation?

Comment: Just updated the question. I want second line to align with first and third.

Comment: To clarify, the equations are already aligned: the `&` are all aligned (that is, the `=` are all aligned).  In an align environment, the individual pieces alternate right and left alignment.  The answers change your alignment by moving around the `&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both the material to the left of the `=` symbols to be left-aligned *and* the `=` symbols to be aligned vertically as well, you should use an `alignedat` environment instead of a `split` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
We recall the Bellman equation
\begin{equation} \label{eq:bellman-eq} 
    \begin{alignedat}{2} 
    &Q^{\pi}_{h}(s, a) &&= (r_h + \mathbb{P}_h V^{\pi}_{h+1})(s, a),\\
    &V^{\pi}_{h}(s)    &&= \langle Q^{\pi}_{h}(s,\cdot), \pi_h(\cdot \mid s) \rangle,\\ 
    &V^{\pi}_{H+1}(s)  &&= 0 
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

We recall the Bellman equation
\begin{align} \label{eq:bellman-eq} 
  &Q^{\pi}_{h}(s, a) = (r_h + \mathbb{P}_h V^{\pi}_{h+1})(s, a),\notag \\
  &V^{\pi}_{h}(s) = \langle Q^{\pi}_{h}(s,\cdot), \pi_h(\cdot \mid s) \rangle,\\ 
  &V^{\pi}_{H+1}(s) = 0 \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Also, `split` and `aligned` can be used:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split} \label{eq:bellman-eq} 
    &Q^{\pi}_{h}(s, a) = (r_h + \mathbb{P}_h V^{\pi}_{h+1})(s, a),\\
    &V^{\pi}_{h}(s) = \langle Q^{\pi}_{h}(s,\cdot), \pi_h(\cdot \mid s) \rangle,\\ 
    &V^{\pi}_{H+1}(s) = 0 
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```